# Custom comment types. Are they a possibility?

Tags: comments

I see everywhere this has been discussed, there still isn't a good answer out there.  I don't want to create a custom post type and associate it that way.  I want a custom comment type so editors in the backend can add comments on posts while they're in the editorial phase before it goes out and we need to display those comments in the backend as well but, also keep them separate to where those comment won't display on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, core only has `comment`, `trackback`, and `pingback` registered as comment types, and that list is not extensible.

I would recommend using **custom post metadata** for your editorial-phase comments.

Comment: While that isn't a bad idea, I think I've come up with my own solution.

I'm going to use a custom post type that acts as a sub post to the original post with the post_parent set on the sub post.  Then I'll just pull in the comments from that sub post on the post edit screen so the validation and everything with the comments is already good.

Comment: Well, I'm of the school of thought that whatever works best <em>for you</em> is the best solution. However, it's ironic that the solution you came up with ("**I'm going to use a custom post type that acts as a sub post to the original post with the post_parent set on the sub post.**") is in direct contradiction to your OP, in which you stated: "**I don't want to create a custom post type and associate it that way.**" :)

Comment: @klangley You should add that to your original Q.